# Sign existing CRT

Tags: openssl

This is my one line to generate self signed certificates

```
openssl req -x509 -out localhost.crt -keyout localhost.key \
  -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 \
  -subj '/CN=example.com' -extensions EXT -config <( \
   printf "[dn]\nCN=example.com\n[req]\ndistinguished_name = dn\n[EXT]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:example.com\nkeyUsage=digitalSignature\nextendedKeyUsage=serverAuth")
```

Now I want to sign previous certificates with my own CA so I issue this:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out rootCA.key 4096
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 1024 -out rootCA.crt
```

How can I sign with my CA an existing CRT ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I sign with my CA an existing CRT ?

You can only sign a certificate request but not a certificate. But you can create a certificate request from an existing certificate and then sign this certificate request. See [Generate CSR from existing certificate](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/104139/generate-csr-from-existing-certificate).

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an unusual thing to do, OpenSSL commandline, which includes a lot of features aimed mainly at debugging problems, can do it. Use `openssl x509` (*without* `-req`) with `-CA certfile -CAkey keyfile` or just `-CA file` if you have both cert and privatekey in one file (which PEM can do). Add `-digestname` e.g. `-sha256` if other than the default (SHA1). 
You can specify the new serial explicitly with `-set_serial`, or use *almost* the same serial-file scheme as `openssl ca` either by default or explicitly; see `man [1ssl?] x509` on your system (unless Windows) or [on the web](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/x509.html) at the heading 'Signing Options' about 1/3 of the way down. (The difference is that `ca` uses the hex value from the file *after* incrementing, but `x509 [-req] -CA*` uses it *before*. The serial/cert mapping is NOT recorded in a 'database' file, as `ca` does.) You can specify the length of the validity period, but cannot specify arbitrary start and end times as `ca` can.

This replaces the issuer name, serial, validity period, and signature, in the new (output) cert, but it does not change any of the extensions, which for your case looks right. If the input cert contains AuthorityKeyIdentifier (AKI) extension to identify its parent/'signing' cert, that extension in the output cert will not correctly identify its parent which may cause trouble in using the cert. You can replace extensions by adding `-clrext -extfile filename -extensions section` -- but you have to do *all* of them, which may be inconvenient.

If you use the two-step process of `x509 -x509toreq` to create a CSR and then either `x509 -req -CA*` or `ca` to issue a cert from that CSR, this discards all extensions from the input cert. If you want any extensions you must add them back: for `x509 -req -CA*` this must be explicit on the command line; for `ca` it can be configured in the config file or overridden on command line.

ObRant: issuing a cert is often described as 'signing the CSR/request'. It is not. The cert body, aka certTBS (TBS = to-be-signed), is normally based *partly on part of* the CSR, but most of the cert body is different from the CSR.